# Can i call an Activity Function from another Activity Function?

Tags: azure-functions

From Orchestrator  i can sub Orchestrators and from that i can call Multiple Activity Functions , is it possible to call Activity Function from another Activity Function. From this can i call GetOrdersFromDb activity function from GetDbToken Activity Function

Consider the below example activity Function in Azure Function Apps

```
[FunctionName("ExpensiveDurableSequence")]
public static async Task<List<string>> Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationTrigger context)
{
    var response = new List<Order>();
    var token = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("GetDbToken", "i-am-root");

    response.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<IEnumerable<Order>>("GetOrdersFromDb", token));
    return response;
}

[FunctionName("GetDbToken")]
public static string GetDbToken([ActivityTrigger] string username)
{
    return token;
}

[FunctionaName("GetOrdersFromDb")]
public static IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersFromDb([ActivityTrigger] string apikey)
{
    return orders;
}
```

Comment: Currently, It is not supported to call an activity function outside an Orchestration function. Because to invoke an activity function we need a DurableOrchestrationTrigger object. See github issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/160

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not call activities from activities.
Orchestrators handle the *orchestration* of activities; they should be in control of the workflow.

What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?